# What is the units used for the 'Z' values or the 'Elevation' values in the USGS LIDAR data?

Tags: gis, lidar

USGS provides multiple laz files which have X, Y and Z values, my question is, what is the units used for the 'elevation' or the Z values in the laz file? Metres, centimetres, feet or something else?

Comment: USGS (and most serious data providers) give you information and metadata about the data. You should always read it (they provide also comments on the methodic errors, and other things one may need to consider)

Comment: Hey, can you please point me to the metadata of a certain project, I'm fairly new to working with LIDAR data

Comment: It is where you get the data (it is standard on nearly every georeferencing data) . E.g. in https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/ss/3dep-product-metadata but I have no idea on which data you are using.